# Security risks using SUDO in TERMINAL on MAC

Tags: macos, security, terminal, sudo

I'm very new to using Terminal and anything like that and stupidly followed an article that uses Terminal with the SUDO command. The sudo command basically loaded a file which updated my /private/etc/hosts file. I opened the file and made sure it was just doing this and nothing else.

Nothing went wrong, but later on I read that this was a bit silly and that it has opened up my machine to all kinds of security attacks. First of all, I'd like this statement verified "open to security attacks". Have I really? If yes, what steps can be taken to resecure things. This is what I used in Terminal:

The Terminal Commands

```
sudo -s
[enter password]
sh updateOSXHostFile
```

**The file:**

```
echo "Do you wish to update your host file ?"
select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
    case $yn in
        Yes ) echo "0.0.0.0 yahoo.com" >> /etc/hosts;
              echo "0.0.0.0 www.yahoo.com" >> /etc/hosts;
              break;;
        No ) break;;
    esac
done
```

Which successfully updated the hosts file to block access to specific sites.

Comment: What were the contents of the script you ran?

Comment: @BrianAdkins: It was literally about 6 lines of ip addresses and url's to block access to.

Comment: @BrianAdkins: added code from file in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running a command using sudo is no different than running a command as an administrator on windows.

What's really important is "what you did" while using those elevated permissions. If you simply added IP addresses to your hosts file that effectively blackhole certain sites (common for ad-blocking), then you are fine...

If the script you ran redefines google's address by pointing you to a malicious server instead (DNS poisoning), or something else nefarious, then you're in trouble.

Based on the script you've provided, you're fine... But yahoo is dead to you.

Related article about black-holing specific sites : http://someonewhocares.org/hosts/zero/ (that's how to go overboard with this method)

I prefer using [opendns](http://opendns.com) to the method above.

Answer (score 2):

By executing a script with `sudo` you are giving it **superuser** privileges. So anything the script is programmed to do, is going to be done by root (superuser). How risky it is depends on who programmed the script. Or more precisely what the script does.

As a general rule you should not execute such a script unless you trust the source.

In your particular case: if the script modified the `hosts` file, it could place a line like:

```
199.55.22.33    www.yourbank.com
```

Using an IP address which doesn't belong to your bank. And that would be a pretty good start for phishing.

UPDATE: As you published the code we can see this script is trying to block access to **yahoo.com**. which seems harmless. But even if a script only messes with the hosts file, it could be dangerous.